# various problems with connecting to a local DB using JS and ADO

Tags: javascript, ado

**General Problem:**
I am tasked with creating a time tracking software that will work locally (no internet access) but also sync with a server database when prompted (and also allow online access to server db using html)

**General Approach:**
I decided to use a local access DB and try to connect using ADO and Javascript.

**Question 1:**
I found some code that allows me to easily connect to the mdb file, BUT there is some weird behaviour when specifying the filepath:

```
var cn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = C:\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents\timeTracking\employees.mdb;Persist Security Info=False";
cn.Open(strConn);
```

The above code returned the error "Not a valid filename". So, since the html file is in the same folder as the mdb, I tried just "employees.mdb" and it returned the error "C:\Documents and Settings\username\Desktop\employees.mdb does not exist".
Why was it looking in Desktop? I placed the file on the Desktop and it worked fine, but I just want to understand what is going on.

Thanks

Comment: You should consider splitting this into three different questions.  The topics they cover are pretty diverse.

Comment: Good idea...I'll do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1:**

In JavaScript strings, backslashes are special characters, so you need to escape them:

```
var strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\My Documents\\timeTracking\\employees.mdb;Persist Security Info=False";
```

Comment: Sigh...i feel like an idiot...it's like forgetting a semi-colon and spending hours trying to figure out what's wrong.
btw...thank you :)